# JPA/Hibernate Embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I would like to do something like that:

- An object ReportingFile that can be a LogRequest or a LogReport file. ( both got the same structure)
- An object Reporting containing for one logRequest, a list of logReport with a date.

I tryed to set an EmbededId, that would be an attribute of the logRequest. And that's the problem i got. I don't arrive to mannage embedded id. ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier )

If you have a clue on how i should do it :)

An example (not working) would be:

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverride( name="logRequest.fileName", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="log_request_file_name") } )
public class Reporting {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReportingFile logRequest;

    @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_reports", schema="", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "log_report")})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<ReportingFile> reports;

    @Column(name="generated_date",nullable=true)
    private Date generatedDate;

    [...]
}

@Embeddable
public class ReportingFile {

    @Column(name="file_name",length=255)
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name="xml_content")
    private Clob xmlContent;

    [...]
}
```

In this sample, i have a the following error:

```
    15.03.2010 16:37:59 [ERROR] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader       Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [config/persistenceContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [config/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:366)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [config/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:270)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:125)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering Reporting from Reporting has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1319)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:253)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, let's see

You have a @AssociationOverride annotation which its [API](http://fl-hotel-orlando.technology-related.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html) says:

> This annotation is used **to override a many-to-one or one-to-one** mapping of property or field for an entity relationship.

And

> It may be applied **to an entity that extends a mapped superclass** to override a many-to-one or one-to-one mapping defined by the mapped superclass

I have not seen neither @ManyToOne nor @OnoToOne in your question. So, There is something wrong with your question.

But i have seen the following log in your StackTrace

> A Foreign key refering Reporting from Reporting has the wrong number of column. should be 2

**You have a Compound primary key** defined by a @EmbeddedId annotation which has two properties (fileName and xmlContent)

Now, let's see your @CollectionOfElements

```
@CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="t_reports", 
    // Your mistake goes here
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="log_report"))
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<ReportingFile> reports;
```

Its Foreign key just contains **one property** whereas your Compound primary key contains **two properties**. **Both must match**. It explains why you see this nice message

> A Foreign key refering Reporting from Reporting has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Your right mapping should looks like this

```
@CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="t_reports", 
    joinColumns={
        // The number of columns defined by our Compound primary key (2)
        // must match the number of columns defined by its Foreign key (2)
        @JoinColumn(name="file_name", referencedColumnName="file_name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="xml_content", referencedColumnName="xml_content")})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<ReportingFile> reports;
```

And more: i do not know whether your target database supports a Clob as primary key. So keep it in mind.

**Added to original answer according to your reply**

*1º* First scenario (**without** @CollectionOfElements)

```
@Entity
public class Reporting {

    // You said you just want a single fileName as primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name="file_name", nullable=false)
    private String fileName;

    // You said you still want to have the whole ReportingFile object
    @Embedded
    private ReportingFile reportingFile;

    @Embeddable
    public static class ReportingFile implements Serializable {

        // You must set up insertable=false, updatable=false
        @Column(name="file_name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private String fileName;

        @Column(name="xml_content")
        private Clob xmlContent;

   }

}
```

Keep in mind the following: Hibernate **does not allow you define two properties where both share the same column**. Because of that, i have to define insertable=false, updatable=false in fileName property.

And when i do the following

```
Reporting reporting = new Reporting();
reporting.setFileName("home.pdf");

ReportingFile reportingFile = new ReportingFile();
// It will not persisted because of insertable=false, updatable=false
reportingFile.setFileName("home.pdf");
reportingFile.setXmlContent(someClobObject);

session.save(reporting); // It works
```

*2º* First scenario (**with** @CollectionOfElements)

```
@Entity
public class Reporting {

    // You said you just want a single fileName as primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name="file_name", nullable=false)
    private String fileName;

    // You said you still want to have the whole ReportingFile object
    @Embedded
    private ReportingFile reportingFile;

    @CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="t_reports",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="file_name", referencedColumnName="file_name", insertable=false, updatable=false))
    private List<ReportingFile> reports;

    @Embeddable
    public static class ReportingFile implements Serializable {

        // You must set up insertable=false, updatable=false
        @Column(name="file_name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private String fileName;

        @Column(name="xml_content")
        private Clob xmlContent;

   }

}
```

And when i do the following

```
Reporting reporting = new Reporting();
reporting.setFileName("home.pdf");

ReportingFile reportingFile = new ReportingFile();
// It will not persisted because of insertable=false, updatable=false
reportingFile.setFileName("home.pdf");
reportingFile.setXmlContent(someClobObject);

reporting.getReports().add(reportingFile);

session.save(reporting); // It does not work
```

Hibernate will complain

> repeated column in mapping for collection: reports column: file_name

So, when you have a @CollectionOfElements which shares a foreign key, **it will not work as expected**. But you can do a workaround

```
@Entity
public class Reporting {

    // You said you just want a single fileName as primary key
    @Id
    @Column(name="file_name", nullable=false)
    private String fileName;

    // You said you still want to have the whole ReportingFile object
    @Embedded
    private ReportingFile reportingFile;

    // Your workaround goes here
    @CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="t_reports",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="file_name", referencedColumnName="file_name"))
    private List<Clob> xmlContents;

    @Transient
    public List<ReportingFile> getReports() {
        List<ReportingFile> reports = new ArrayList<ReportingFile>();

        for(Clob xmlContent: getXmlContents())
            reports.add(new ReportingFile(getFileName(), xmlContent));

        return reports;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class ReportingFile implements Serializable {

        // required no-arg  constructor
        public ReportingFile() {}

        public ReportingFile(String fileName, Clob xmlContent) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.xmlContent = xmlContent;
        }

        // You must set up insertable=false, updatable=false
        @Column(name="file_name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private String fileName;

        @Column(name="xml_content")
        private Clob xmlContent;

   }

}
```

Notice you can define a @Embeddable class as static when using inside your owning class.

Comment: Ok thank you !

The fact is, i wanted to have only fileName as primary key, like you said, to avoid using a Clob as primary key.

But i don't know how to specify to the EmbeddedId (and if it's possible) that it should take only the fileName attribute of the ReportingFile.

That's what i tried to do with the @AssociationOverride. (with the mistake you highlighted) 

That's also why in my @CollectionOfElements, i wanted to have only one param.

Comment: So, I changed that ( adding @OneToOne):
 @OneToOne
 @Column(name="file_name",length=255)
 private String fileName;
in order to respect the API.

I have the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to define a @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association: logRequest.fileName

It seems that it's not the way to chose only one param for the PK.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was not really clear ;)
I only want the fileName (logRequest.fileName) as PK of the Reporting, but i still want to have the whole ReportingFile object ( more the private List<ReportingFile> reports; ).

In what you suggest me, i'll lose the "content" of my file.

If i added  @Column(name="xml_content") private Clob xmlContent;
to the Reporting class you gave, it would be ok, but i would not use the "ReportingFile" object for this (which is exactly a fileName + content ).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was more complicated than expected :D