# Hibernate Referencing Embedded ID columns in FK

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a problem mapping multiple `@EmbeddedId` columns of different entity classes. I have an entity structure like the following (have simplified the entities for readability).

#### Entity: Action

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name="pk.method", column=@Column(name = "http_method", nullable = false)) })
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.operation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", nullable = false)) })
public class Action {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ActionId pk = new ActionId();


}
```

This entity has an `@EmbeddedId` defined as the following:

```
@Embeddable
private class ActionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne private Operation operation;
    private HttpMethod method;

}
```

The mappings here between the pk columns work fine. The problems come when I attempt to add another entity which is a link table to the `Action` entity. This link table also has an `@EmbeddedId`.

#### Entity: UserAction

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides .. ?
public class UserAction {

    @EmbeddedId private UserActionId pk = new UserActionId();
}
```

The `@EmbeddedId` class looks like:

```
@Embeddable
private class UserActionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne private Action action;
    @ManyToOne private User user;


}
```

How to I reference the `@EmbeddedId` fields of the Action class, but only one of the columns is a join column. The other column in the `ActionId` class is a regular `@Column`.

I have tried this:

```
@AssociationOverrides({ 
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.action.pk.operation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_operation", nullable = false)) })
```

But this is giving me an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_gwvslpytxm695kdw5lxqneyss:user_action [useraction])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (useraction[id_operation,http_method])
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1816)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1739)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)

How do i override the other non-join column `method` association of the `ActionId` class in the UserAction entity?

Comment: I had a similar problem to this, this helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448409/jpa-hibernate-embedded-id